# React Fetch Google API 404 not found

Tags: reactjs, google-api

Trying to fetch a google api with react but I am receiving a 404 error. A little more background is I am building a web app that uses googles book api to send me back a value when I type a book name. I am unsure what I am doing wrong. I've tried a lot of things I am doing a course where we are supposed to do this and I have my code identical to the instructors. I think it has to do something with perhaps privileges on local host 3000? But then again I am unsure.

Heres my code

```
~import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, InputGroup, Glyphicon } from 'react-bootstrap';

class Global extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            query: ''
        }
    }

search() {
    const BASE_URL = 'https://googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q='
    fetch(`${BASE_URL}${this.state.query}`, { 
      method: 'GET',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json));
}
render() {
    return(
        <div className="Global">
            <h2> Book Explorer!</h2>
            <FormGroup>
                <InputGroup>
                    <FormControl
                      type="text"
                      placeholder="Search for a book"
                      onChange={event => this.setState({query: event.target.value})}
                      onKeyPress={event => {
                        if (event.key === 'Enter') {
                            this.search();
                        }
                      }}
                      />
                      <InputGroup.Addon onClick={() => this.search()}>
                      <Glyphicon glyph="search"></Glyphicon>
                      </InputGroup.Addon>
                      </InputGroup>
                      </FormGroup>
                     </div>


)
}
}



export default Global;
```

Comment: Have you copied & pasted the exact URL into your web browser to see what response you're getting?

Comment: ... that URL definitely doesn't exist, no matter how you try to access it. It may have changed, or be otherwise no longer available

Answer (score 0):

```
search() {
    const BASE_URL = 'https://googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q='
    fetch(`${BASE_URL}${this.state.query}`, { 
      method: 'GET',
      headers:{
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials':true,
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'POST, GET'
      }
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json));
}
```

Just added `headers` key to the options

Comment: Just tried :( I was reloading the host 3000 server but still the same 404 error cannot fetch api

Comment: Hey would you want to use something so that perhaps I can screen share and you can see my end?

Comment: this is my error message in a screen shot also https://puu.sh/vNTyv/7ab2c25757.png

Comment: Sounds good, however I'm a bit tired now since it's 3:00 AM at my place in Tokyo, so how about a few hours later ^^

Comment: Yeah Thinh that sounds great I'll work on other stuff and maybe you can help me later if you get some free time just message me or comment on here. I appreciate it a lot man!